# C# Regex for Web.config Rewrite Url

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following url 
    www.localproject.com:843/user/validate/eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJ0ZW1wVXJsIjoie1wiQ3VzdG9tZXJJZFwiOjEsXCJDb3Vyc2VJZFwiOjEsXCJUb2tlblwiOm51bGwsXCJFeHBpcnlcIjpcIjIwMTgtMDQtMThUMTc6MzU6MTMuOTQ2MjM2NCswNTowMFwifSJ9uvm7jZ3us5UFa1hqh4bod2cSamcxF2rRUbfxs7DHQs

from which I need to extract only 10 to 30 characters after **validate** including numbers etc. For example, I need only this

```
eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d
```

what should be the regex? I tried following but it not working

```
^api/user/validate/(^([a-zA-Z\d]){50})
```

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew any idea?

Comment: What is that second `^` intended to do in your regex?

Comment: Why not use string.substring (since "www.localproject.com:843/user/validate" is of a known length)?

Comment: Why not just use substring with `LastIndexOf('/')`? It isn't clear how much of the query string you need...

Comment: I am using this in web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
api\/user\/validate\/(.{23})
```

Can see it working here - https://regex101.com/r/Xr6Ueo/1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regex or `Substring`.  If the string is stored in web.config you can still get to it with [ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  I recommend taking the parts you do not need out of the `Uri`.  This way once you deploy to prod there's less of a chance of things breaking down.

```
var input = new Uri("www.localproject.com:843/user/validate/eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJ0ZW1wVXJsIjoie1wiQ3VzdG9tZXJJZFwiOjEsXCJDb3Vyc2VJZFwiOjEsXCJUb2tlblwiOm51bGwsXCJFeHBpcnlcIjpcIjIwMTgtMDQtMThUMTc6MzU6MTMuOTQ2MjM2NCswNTowMFwifSJ9uvm7jZ3us5UFa1hqh4bod2cSamcxF2rRUbfxs7DHQs");
var environmentAgnosticPath = input.Segments[input.Segments.Length - 1];//take just the part after /validate

//example output: eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d
//I don't know what you mean by 10 - 30 since the example is 23 characters
var resultFromSubstring = environmentAgnosticPath.Substring(0,23);

var pattern = @"[A-Za-z0-9]{10,23}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
var resultFromRegex = regex.Match(environmentAgnosticPath).Value;
```

And generally [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great playground for figuring out the regex part.